# Use Totem and Image viewer dark theme as the main Gnome 3 theme?

Tags: gnome, themes

I like Totem and Image viewer dark theme of adwaita as my main theme instead of the light one.

Anybody knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i've found the solution :

http://felipe.netai.net/proyectos/gnome-shell/themes/Adwaita-Dark.tar.gz